# Websites to find work in Sweden as a foreigner

Tags: working, sweden

My acquaintance from the Ukraine urgently needs money to pay medical treatment for her mother. She has a work permission for Sweden and quickly can move from the Ukraine to Sweden. She doesn't speak Swedish but speaks English. On which websites she could find a position that would help to alleviate her situation?

Comment: You cannot get a work permit for Sweden without a job offer. It is possible to work without a work permit in certain situations, but there is no indication that these apply here.

Are you sure that you are not being scammed?

Comment: This case doesn't apply here

Comment: Unless your acquaintance has permanent residency (and even then in some cases) they can't leave Sweden for a long period and come back to a different job. Do they have specific skills ? that will help over the generic web sites people already provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [The Swedish public employment service](https://arbetsformedlingen.se/platsbanken/)
- [Monster](https://www.monster.se/)

Does she speak Swedish? If not, it might be easiest to to get a job at international companies, depending on profsession of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places you can look, but a lot of it will depend on your friend's profession. There are probably several industry-specific sites.

Here are some of the biggest:

- [LinkedIn](https://linkedin.com/) is probably the world's biggest job web site.
- [Blocket Jobs](https://jobb.blocket.se/) is Sweden's largest job website.*
- [EURES](https://ec.europa.eu/eures/public/homepage) The European Job Mobility Portal.
- [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/) Another large, global, job site.
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) also has a jobs site.

---

Disclaimer: Blocket will be my employer in a few weeks.